# Mongodb $geoIntersects giving wrong query results

Tags: mongodb, geolocation, mongodb-query, polygon, geo

I'm facing a rather strange issue with mongodb when I try to get which of my stored polygons intersects with the given area and its throwing results when it should't.

This is what I have stored:
[image]

It is the only one element stored in mongo and looks like this in a map:
[image]

Now this is the query (among others) that is giving me trouble :

```
db.getCollection('collection').find({"geometry": {"$geoIntersects": {"$geometry":{"coordinates":[[
        [
          -25.13671875,
          16.636191878397664
        ],
        [
          -21.796875,
          16.636191878397664
        ],
        [
          -21.796875,
          19.145168196205297
        ],
        [
          -25.13671875,
          19.145168196205297
        ],
        [
          -25.13671875,
          16.636191878397664
        ]]],"type":"Polygon"}}}})
```

which in a map looks like this (including the previous mentioned area):
[image]

As you can see in the map (or doing simple math calc with the coordinates) those areas do not intersect at all, but mongo insists they do as the query gives me results.
 I've tried using the following in **$geometry** operator but the results are the same

```
crs: {
    type: "name",
    properties: { name: "urn:x-mongodb:crs:strictwinding:EPSG:4326" }
}
```

Last but not least, if the area in the query is east/west/south of the stored one the results are the expected ones, the problem is in areas in close vicinity north of the main polygon.

What am I doing wrong?

Please let me know if more data is needed and thank you all for your time.

Comment: I am facing similar issue, did anybody find any solution for it ?